# Typescript: Creating self in an abstract class

Tags: typescript

I have 2 **immutable** classes which extends an abstract class which looks as follows:

```
abstract class Enemy {
    abstract readonly attackPower: number;

    constructor(
        public readonly health: number
    ) {
    }

    abstract hit(): Enemy;

}

class Boss extends Enemy {
    attackPower = 100;
    
    hit(): Boss {
        return new Boss(this.health - 1);
    }
}

class NormalEnemy extends Enemy {
    attackPower = 5;

    hit(): NormalEnemy {
        return new NormalEnemy(this.health - 1);
    }
}
```

Note these are immutable classes, so all properties are read-only.

As you can see the "hit" method is being repeated.

Ideally I would like to move to logic to the `Enemy` abstract class to something like:

```
abstract class Enemy {
    abstract readonly attackPower: number;

    constructor(
        public readonly health: number
    ) {
    }

    hit() {
         return new self(health - 1); // not valid TypeScript code
    }
}


class Boss extends Enemy {
    attackPower = 100;
}

class NormalEnemy extends Enemy {
    attackPower = 5;
}
```

However this is of course not valid.

Anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: What if you want a new enemy to take more damage than just `1`?

Comment: @kelly For this example, we don't need to consider that case. But I imagine you could just add an argument to hit, such as `hit(attack: number)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `this.constructor` in a similar manner:

```
abstract class Enemy<ChildClass extends Enemy<any>> {
    abstract readonly attackPower: number;

    constructor(
        public readonly health: number
    ) {
    }

    hit(): ChildClass {
         return new (this.constructor as { new (...args: any[]): ChildClass })(this.health - 1);
    }
}
```

I have added a generic to `Enemy` so that `hit` returns the correct type, and also so that we can cast `this.constructor` to the correct type (creates instance of ChildClass).

This is what the child classes look like now:

```
class Boss extends Enemy<Boss> {
    attackPower = 100;
}

class NormalEnemy extends Enemy<NormalEnemy> {
    attackPower = 5;
}
```

And if we test it, it works:

```
let boss = new Boss(10);

boss = boss.hit();

console.log(boss, boss.health);
/*
Boss: {
  "health": 9,
  "attackPower": 100
},  9 
*/
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7yGDW)

---

If you really want something similar to "self" in other languages, you could store `new.target` and use that in the `hit` method:

```
abstract class Enemy<ChildClass extends Enemy<any>> {
    abstract readonly attackPower: number;

    private readonly self;

    constructor(
        public readonly health: number
    ) {
        this.self = new.target;
    }

    hit(): ChildClass {
         return new (this.self as { new(...args: any[]): ChildClass })(this.health - 1);
    }
}
```

[new.target reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)